# Display Suite ignores hook_preprocess_node()

Tags: nodes, theming, display-suite

It seems like the *Display Suite* module completely ignores `hook_preprocess_node()` and `hook_process_node()`. Is this the case?

If it is so, what is the way to make minor changes to the final rendering with access to all the node variables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Display Suite does indeed hijack the node rendering to a point where the default preprocess functions may not be used.

The module comes with a set of its own preprocess functions that are documented in [ds.api.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/ds.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/ds.api.php).

In this case, `hook_ds_pre_render_alter()` can be used instead of the `hook_preprocess_node()` to modify the output via the complete render array. Also, the `$entity` object is available with all values.

Comment: how can i get $enitity in this hook

Comment: @MobyM you can find it in the variable `$context["entity"]`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to trigger it using `hook_preprocess_ds_entity_view()`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_ds_entity_view(&$variables) {
  $variables['node'] = $variables['content']['#node'];
  $variables['view_mode'] = $variables['content']['#view_mode'];

  mytheme_preprocess_node($variables);
}
```