# Why doesn't hook_preprocess_node() get triggered?

Tags: theming

I use the following code in a theme whose machine name is yokai.

```
// works like expected, output visible
function yokai_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  dpm('yokai_preprocess_html');
  dpm($variables);
}

// does not work, no output visible
function yokai_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  dpm('yokai_preprocess_node');
  dpm($variables);
}
```

Why doesn't `hook_preprocess_node()` get triggered?

Comment: It looks like this is by design and DS hijacks `HOOK_preprocess_node()` like described over [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/95626/3965). I assume this is still the case in Drupal 8?

Comment: Did you clear all caches? Btw, `dsm()` is just calling `dpm()`, there's no need to do the same thing twice. Just use `dpm()`. You can see the source [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/8).

Comment: just used both to see if either of them works. Rebuilt the cache several times with drush `dr cr`.

Comment: Strange; the code looks OK; there's nothing else that comes to my mind. Maybe someone else will be able to point you in the right direction. I would try to do this from another theme - even hack Bartik temporarily and see if `hook_preprocess_node()` works from there.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is either you are not printing the $messages, you misspelled the theme name.. try putting an exit in there and you'll know the code is being hit. I also recommend xdebug in instances just like this.

Comment: It looks like the above code. I copied it from my theme file. Therefore the misspelling can not be an issue and neither the $message because like mentioned above, the `dpm()`'s in `yokai_preprocess_html` get displayed, therefore called and output.

Comment: Apart from printing a debug message with `dpm()` what else are you doing to be sure Drupal is going to invoke that preprocess function? What page are you visiting? If it's a custom page, what code is that page executing?

Comment: Enable twig debugging and use a DOM inspector. Check if the node.html.twig is even being printed in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `dpm()`. This uses `drupal_set_message()`, which uses the session variable to store messages:

```
function dpm($input, $name = NULL, $type = 'status') {
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access devel information')) {
    $export = kprint_r($input, TRUE, $name);
    drupal_set_message($export, $type, TRUE);
  }
  return $input;
}
```

When the node template is processed, the page is already built with the session variables at this point. Any messages that come later will not make it on the page. In this case better use kint(). dpm() is more usefull for debugging code that doesn't produce a page output, like form validation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately `kint()` does not work either. I tried to log if the `HOOK_preprocess_node` with `\Drupal::logger('theme')->notice('yokai_preprocess_node was called');` which does not work either therefore the HOOK never gets called. If I log `HOOK_preprocess_html` like that `\Drupal::logger('theme')->notice('yokai_preprocess_html was called');` everything works like expected and I can see the msg in the watchdog.

Comment: what could cause that `HOOK_preprocess_node` does not get called? Never occurred to me before.

Comment: I wanted to point out, that this is not easy to debug with dpm(). Other than that I could think of two reasons 1) the node is cached 2) the page has no node. Did you enable Twig debugging as suggested by Eyal? Then look, if there is `<!-- THEME HOOK: 'node' -->` in your html source.

Comment: Page is definitely a node and Twig debugging is on too.

Created a super basic new content type (only body field and no config) which does not use Display Suite nor Paragraphs (enabled for my other content types) and `HOOK_preprocess_node ` gets triggered and I can see the notice in the watchdog. 

Now checking if DS or Paragraphs is causing this ...

Comment: DS is causing the not calling of `HOOK_preprocess_node`. Until I enable a Display Suite layout the HOOK gets called, but just after enabling the default One-Column layout `HOOK_preprocess_node` does not anymore get called

Comment: DS brings its own templates: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ds/tree/templates?h=8.x-2.3